# What are these characters called and how can I normalize them?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an online chat where users have begun typing with some awkwardly spaced characters, such as `ｐａｓｓｉｏｎ`...

What are these characters called and how would I convert/normalize them to `passion` using ActionScript 3?

Answer (score 1):

Those are latin characters, (for more info see [here](http://graphemica.com/%EF%BD%90)) one way of converting them is to map them to their ascii counterparts. Here is a sample app that does it just for the characters `ｐａｓｓｉｏｎ`

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    private var mapping:Object = {
        "ｐ": "p",
        "ａ": "a",
        "ｓ": "s",
        "ｉ": "i",
        "ｏ": "o",
        "ｎ": "n"
    };
    public function Main():void 
    {
        var test:String = "ｐａｓｓｉｏｎ";

        trace(filter(test));
    }

    public function filter(string:String):String {
        var returnString:String = "";
        for (var i:int; i < string.length; ++i) {
            var char:String = string.charAt(i);
            returnString += mapping[char] ? mapping[char] : string.charAt(i);
        }
        return returnString;
    }

}
```

Comment: So they're called fullwidth characters? Cool. Is there not a way to convert them without having to map every character? When converting `ａｂｃ` to decimal, I got `239 189 129, 
239 189 130, 239 189 131` so they appear to be sequential, just like `abc` is `97, 98, 99`... Ideally, I'd like to get rid of all fullwidth characters where a normal one exists to replace it.

Comment: Yeah if you can do it with ranges even better, you would need to check the uppercase versions as well.